# Efficiently grouping the rows of a Pandas DataFrame by the value of a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame `df`, with two columns `A` and `B`. `A` is also the index.

`B` has a very small range of permissible values (in my case, `B` is a boolean). How do I quickly answer the query: "all rows in `df` for which the value of `B` is `x`?"

For example, "which rows of `df` have a `B` value that is `True`?"

For my particular usecase, since there's only two columns, just grouping the values in the `A` column would be enough, i.e. "which values of `A` have a corresponding `B` value that is `x`?".

Comment: You probably don't need to group here just do `df[df['B'] == True]` or generically `df['df['B'] == x]`

Comment: You could also try the [`eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval) method so something like `df.eval('B =val')` which may be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using http://www.gregreda.com/2013/10/26/intro-to-pandas-data-structures/ also I recommend you going over that tutorial along with the pandas documentation.

```
>>> data = {'year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012],
...         'team': ['Bears', 'Bears', 'Bears', 'Packers', 'Packers', 'Lions', 'Lions', 'Lions'],
...         'wins': [11, 8, 10, 15, 11, 6, 10, 4],
...         'losses': [5, 8, 6, 1, 5, 10, 6, 12]}
>>> football = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'team', 'wins', 'losses'])
>>> football
   year     team  wins  losses
0  2010    Bears    11       5
1  2011    Bears     8       8
2  2012    Bears    10       6
3  2011  Packers    15       1
4  2012  Packers    11       5
5  2010    Lions     6      10
6  2011    Lions    10       6
7  2012    Lions     4      12
```

This is what you wanted to do:

```
>>> football[football['team'] == 'Lions']
   year   team  wins  losses
5  2010  Lions     6      10
6  2011  Lions    10       6
7  2012  Lions     4      12

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

In your case you need to replace these column headers and do what you want to obtain from the data frame.

```
df[df['B'] = True]
```

I gave above example so you can get more familiar with the operation and play around to get a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, though I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to get all groups. That is, if there are `N` possible values for column `B`, have a method to return `N` dataframes, each being the subset of `df` for which `B`'s value is `x`.

Comment: @DunPeal this seems like a different question than your original question? Or did I miss something?